# How to setting LDAP for permanent on Liferay 6.2

Tags: mysql, ldap, liferay-6.2

I'm newbie with Liferay, i'm using Liferay 6.2 CE ga 4 Tomcat 7.0.42.

My liferay connect to :

1. Database using MySQL (potal-ext.properties)
2. User authentication using LDAP (follow the
   instructions from [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/integrating-existing-users-into-liferay-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-17-en) and [here](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/10/liferay-ldap-integration_8.html))

It's worked, but when i stop and start again (restart) apache my liferay back to the first settings (fresh download). When i want use liferay i should setting again in Control Panel > Setting > Authentication > LDAP.

So, anyone can help me ?

*my english not good, i hope u all understand what i means :P

Answer (score 0):

In order to add LDAP configuration permanently on your Liferay you have to put configuration on your portal-ext.properties.

Keys looks like

```
ldap.base.provider.url.0=
ldap.base.dn.0=
ldap.security.principal.0=
ldap.security.credentials.0=

ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.import.enabled=true
ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.auth.search.filter.0=
ldap.user.mappings.0=
ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=
```

This configuration will be the default configuration if none is set by the control panel. If there is another configuration set bu the control (stored on the database), it will be this one which will be use by Liferay.